# Filled contour with not ascending coordinates R

Tags: r, lattice

I have a data frame like this

```
head(df)
 x        y             z

 97       7      -1.25082912
 76       5      -0.08161392
 79       5      -2.03714142
 77       5      -1.05682487
 93       5       3.49042435 
 78       6      -1.17590179
```

I managed to produce a level plot with

```
library("lattice")
library("latticeExtra")

levelplot(z ~ x * y, data = df,col.regions=colorscale)
```

where

```
colorscale <- colorRampPalette(c("blue","white","red"), space="Lab")(256)
```

What I would like to do is a `filled.contour` plot with the same colorscale but this require having `x` and `y` in ascending order which is not true in my case.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with `levelplot`?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with level plot I just want a interpolated plot